# Create lecture notes

Tags: beamer

I want to create a beamer template, which should be used for lecture notes. Each lecture should start with a short table of content of the entire plan of the course. Like the first lecture is about “Introduktion og ligevægte” next lecture is about “Reaktioner” etc. The lecture that is given at the time should be highlighted with a blue marking.

Afterwards should a small table of contents be shown of what the current lecture will be about. In the bottom of the slides at the center the page numbers should be shown as well as the total number of pages. This should only be for the specific lecture. So the page number will start from 1 again at a new lecture as well as the total number of pages will be start over. The page numbers should be written as 3/14 fx. 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have shown minimal examples of the stucture.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[subsectionstyle=hide]
 \end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[sections=1]
 \end{frame}


\section{Introduktion og ligevægte}
 \begin{frame}{Introduktion og ligevægte}
  Something text here
 \end{frame}

 \subsection{1 subsection}
 \begin{frame}
 Something text here
  \end{frame}

 \section{Reaktioner}
  \begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection,subsectionstyle=hide]%
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Reaktioner}
  Something text here
  \end{frame}

  \end{document}
```

As it can be seen, I short title is missing at the top, and the section in toc should not be shadded. They should be normal text, but the current section should be shown with blue.Also numbers at the sections must be added.

Comment: Please add a MWE and show what's your problem. In `beamer` you can do that with a normal toc. Try for example `\tableofcontents[currentsection,sectionstyle=show/shaded,subsectionstyle=hide/hide/hide]%`

Comment: For notes, what mode are you using? Are these notes for the audience or the lecturer?

Comment: For the audience

Comment: Since the number of lectures in a course is usually more than can fit on a single beamer frame, I put the lecture number and page number in the footline, then show only the current lecture sections/subsections in the table of contents (using the show/shaded/hide options already mentioned). I also `\input` only the current lecture I'm working on, which restarts numbering and saves time compiling.

Comment: You seem to be asking two [or more] unrelated questions, here. On TeX.SX, we try to keep unrelated questions on separate pages. If you have multiple questions that are unrelated to one another, you should ask each in a separate TeX.SX "question". You'll stand a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer to each of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

For highlighting specific parts in the toc, you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\newcommand{\mypause}[1][+]{\onslide<#1>}

\AtBeginSection[]{%
    \begin{frame}<\value{section}>
        \setbeamercovered{%
           still covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}},
           again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}
        }
        \let\pause\mypause
        \tableofcontents[pausesections, subsectionstyle=hide]
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection, sectionstyle=show/hide, subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]
    \end{frame}    

}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[ball]

\begin{document}

\section{Lecture 1}
\begin{frame}
 Something text here
\end{frame}

\subsection{Topic 1}
\begin{frame}
 Something text here
\end{frame}

\subsection{Topic 2}
\begin{frame}
 Something text here
\end{frame}

\section{Lecture 2}
\begin{frame}
 Something text here
\end{frame}

\section{Lecture 3}
\begin{frame}
 Something text here
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]